# Bootstrap Button Color Not Changing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm having some trouble getting the font color to change to white on my button. When I make changes to `.btn-primary` in my CSS I can edit the button exactly how I want, but when I target color nothing happens. I tried going to my `.caption-one button` to change color there and nothing happens either. Not sure what else to try. Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is my html

```
<!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <img src="img/golden_egg3.jpg" class="img-responsive first-slide" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div class="caption-one">
                        <h1>The right Wealth Advisor can make a big difference.</h1>
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg hvr-underline-from-left"><a href="contact.html">Learn More</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS for the button itself:

```
.btn-primary {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    background-color: #50b948; /*Green*/
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

All of the changes I made to the `.btn-primary` shown above happen except color.
adding `!important` did nothing.

My CSS for `.caption-one button` also does nothing

```
.caption-one button {
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying the background change to `.caption-one .btn.btn-primary { }`

Comment: Do you have a live version of this or a jsfiddle so we can more easily see what might be conflicting?

Comment: see answer it is working fine

Comment: This is **invalid HTML** _The interactive element a must not appear as a descendant of the button element._ See [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-constraints). Just use an `a` tag, see the [Button Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags)

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I did to correct the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will re-color the button without needing to rely on `!important`:

```
.caption-one .btn-primary { 
  background: #50b948;
  border-color: #33912c;
}

.caption-one .btn-primary a {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.caption-one .btn-primary:hover { 
  background: #33912c;
}
```

If you applied the `.btn` and `.btn-primary` class to your `<a>` instead of the `<button>` (I'm not sure why you're using an anchor wrapped in a button) you can reduce the total CSS written even further.

Comment: Thanks I just removed the button and kept it a link with adding the .btn and .btn-primary classes to it. Works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.caption-one button a{
    color: #FAFAFA !important;
}
```